# Problems with merging two files with yearly binary data for two overlapping subsets of individuals

Tags: r, merge

I work with mark-recaptures of animals, and I have two capture histories I need to merge. Both files look like this:

[image]

Both files include subsets of the same group of animals, however, all inividuals are not present in both files. Also, one file contains more YEARS (in columns) than the other. The 0's and 1's indicate whether the animal was observed this year or not.

I need to merge both files, ending up with a file that contains all individuals that are included in these files. Observation data need to be merged for those individuals that are present in both files. If observation status for a given animal is 0 in FILE1 and 0 in FILE2, the observation status in the merged file need to be 0, if 0 in FILE1 and 1 in FILE2, observation status in the merged file should be 1, and if 1 in both files, it still needs to be 1 in the merged file (NOT 2).

Below you'll find samples of both files, FILE1 and FILE2. Any help appreciated.

FILE1:

```
> dput(FILE1)
structure(list(ID = c("1", "LL-30", "M-300", "NKW-001", "NKW-002", 
"NKW-003", "NKW-004", "NKW-006", "NKW-007", "NKW-009", "NKW-010", 
"NKW-011", "NKW-012", "NKW-013", "NKW-014", "NKW-015", "NKW-016", 
"NKW-017", "NKW-018", "NKW-019", "NKW-021", "NKW-022", "NKW-023", 
"NKW-024", "NKW-025", "NKW-026", "NKW-028", "NKW-029", "NKW-030", 
"NKW-031", "NKW-032", "NKW-033", "NKW-034", "NKW-035", "NKW-036", 
"NKW-037", "NKW-038", "NKW-039", "NKW-040"), `1986` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1987` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1988` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1989` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1990` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1991` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1992` = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1993` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1994` = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1995` = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1996` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1997` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1998` = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1999` = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2000` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2001` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2002` = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2003` = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2004` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2005` = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2006` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2007` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2008` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2012` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2013` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2014` = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `2015` = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), `2016` = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2017` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `2018` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), `2019` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-39L))
```

FILE2:

```
> dput(FILE2)
structure(list(ID = c("KI03", "KI05", "KI06", "KI07", "KI08", 
"KI10", "NKW-001", "NKW-004", "NKW-005", "NKW-009", "NKW-019", 
"NKW-023", "NKW-025", "NKW-027", "NKW-031", "NKW-032", "NKW-040", 
"NKW-045", "NKW-424", "NKW-431", "NKW-441", "NKW-443"), `2008` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
), `2009` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2010` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2011` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), `2012` = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
), `2013` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `2014` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2015` = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2016` = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0
), `2017` = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `2018` = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2019` = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), `2020` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

Comment: are you just working with two files, or are there more files to merge in your production data?

Comment: Are you trying to merge those columns from FILE2 into FILE1? If so, you can try  `df_result <- merge(FILE1, FILE2, by="ID" , all=FALSE)` . I stored the result into a df called df_result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a scalable `data.table` solution with no merging involved.

If you have got more files, just add them to the list `L`

```
library( data.table )
setDT(df1);setDT(df2) #set to data.table format
L <- list( df1, df2 ) #put the data.tables in a list
#melt all data.tables in the list to long format
L.melt <- lapply( L, melt, id.vars = "ID", variable.name = "year", variable.factor = FALSE )
#rowbind to one large data.table
DT <- data.table::rbindlist( L.melt, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )
#summarise, output a logical TRUE (=1) of FALSE = 0 based on the sum of 0's and 1's
ans <- DT[, .( seen = as.numeric( sum(value) > 0 ) ), by = .(ID, year) ]
#cast to wide again, fill in missing observations in years with 0
dcast( ans, ID ~ year, value.var = "seen", fill = 0 )
```